# Tinymce pragraph tag P add in the textarea during save data

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

By using tinymce when i try to add text like this 
[image]

Then after save the output is

```
pthis is my test editorp
```

but its orginal text is

```
this is my test editor
```

tag P autometically added to my existing text during save data to mysql database.
How can i remove this tag P?

Comment: please, try posting the sample html code (take it from the browser's inspector) which is resulting in undesired behaviour, don't rely on images, there is pretty much nothing we can do with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code. Hope it will work.

```
tinymce.init({ 
        mode:'textareas',
        editor_selector : "mceEditor",
        editor_deselector : "mceNoEditor",
        force_br_newlines : false,
      force_p_newlines : false,
      forced_root_block : ''
    });
```